# insert array data to mysql codeigniter 3

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter, insert

How can I insert array data to mysql using code igniter ??
I tried example from CI documentation like this

```
    $data = array(
        'id_kls' => 'id_kls',
        'fk__id_kls' => 'fk__id_kls',
        'id_reg_pd' => 'id_reg_pd',
        'nm_pd' => 'nm_pd',
        'asal_data' => 'asal_data',
        'nilai_angka' => 'nilai_angka',
        'nilai_huruf' => 'nilai_huruf',
        'nilai_indeks' => 'nilai_indeks',       
);
$this->db->insert('master_nilai', $data);

    // Executes: REPLACE INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date')
```

But not working ..

I have array data like this

```
Array
(
    [error_code] => 0
    [error_desc] => 
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_kls] => f77294f7-2a5a-4876-860b-824d227d5b19
                    [fk__id_kls] => 02
                    [id_reg_pd] => 001be76b-4e58-4cea-96cf-fee2d8e0abdc
                    [nm_pd] => SUYATNO
                    [asal_data] => 9
                    [nilai_angka] => 
                    [nilai_huruf] => B  
                    [nilai_indeks] => 3.00
                )
```

Comment: You can use from `insert_batch('table_name',$your_data)`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you've enable  config/autoload.php/$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
and config/database.php/your hostname,username,dbname!